Differential Item Functioning Criteria Selection
When testing differential item functioning (DIF) using a (ordered) logistic regression framework, a series of (ordered) logistic regressions are fit to the data, using item response ($Y$) as the dependent variable, and as predictors, the latent variable ($θ$), the group variable upon which DIF is being tested ($group$), and their interaction:
$$
Y = \beta_1\theta \tag{1}
$$
$$
Y = \beta_1\theta + \beta_2group \tag{2}
$$
$$
Y = \beta_1\theta + \beta_2group + \beta_3\theta \times group \tag{3}
$$
After calculating these regressions, there appear to be three commonly used criteria for detecting DIF. As outlined in Crane et al. 2007:

In the first criteria, $X^2$ statistics are used to compare the models; if a subsequent model has a significantly higher likelihood, then DIF is present.
In the second criteria, pseudo-$R^2$ is calculated for each model; if a subsequent model has substantially better $R^2$, then DIF is present.
In the third criteria, the $\beta_1$ coefficients are compared; if a subsequent model has a substantially different $\beta_1$ coefficient, then DIF is present.

These criteria make sense to me, but I don't understand why we wouldn't be interested in the effect of $group$ after controlling for the latent variable, i.e., the $\beta_2$ coefficient. If group membership significantly affects the observed response even after controlling for the latent variable, that seems to me to indicate DIF. However, not only does this not seem to be used as a criterion, the only time I've seen it referenced as a method was in Crane et al. 2004, who dismissed it. In comparing method (3) to a method that examined $\beta_2$, they said:

What is of interest in uniform DIF detection is whether the magnitude of the relationship between overall ability level and item responses is altered significantly when taking into account demographic characteristics. This is the essence of confounding and the essence of uniform DIF... We have thus chosen to adopt [the $\beta_1$ criterion] for determination that uniform DIF is present in an item.

Why does a significant $\beta_2$ coefficient not indicate DIF?
Example
This question is motivated by a DIF analysis I'm doing where I'm getting some confusing results. I am comparing PHQ-9 (a measure of depressive symptom severity) responses between college students and non-college student. The total sample size is around 90,000. I am using lordif to test DIF in R.
When I use the first method ($X^2$), I find DIF for all items; it's not surprising that the $X^2$ statistics are significant, given my large sample size, so I test the other two methods.
When I use the second method (change in $R^2$), I find no DIF; no pseudo-$R^2$ measure (McFadden, Nagelkerke, or Cox-Snell) changes more than .01 between models.
When I use the third method (change in $\beta_1$), I also find no DIF; no $\beta_1$ coefficient changes more than 3.3% (even "small" amounts of DIF should be accompanied by a change of at least 5%).
However, when I look at the actual regression results for model $(2)$, I find large and significant $\beta_2$ coefficients. Take item seven on the PHQ-9 (trouble concentrating): the lrm coefficient is 0.789 (OR = 2.2), suggesting that college students have 2.2 times the odds of responding in a higher category than non-college students, after controlling for their latent depression score. The figure below illustrates this difference. This seems like pretty substantial DIF to me, but it doesn't seem to be considered DIF by most people. Why is that?


It's sort of implied that you're talking about IRT (because you've tagged it) but you don't mention in in the body of the question, and so I don't quite understand what you're doing. A reproducible example might help me.

IRT is used to estimate $\theta$. There are also IRT-based methods for estimating DIF (comparing IRT parameters), but those don't seem to be preferred by most folks. It's hard to come up with a reproducible example here but for an intro to the method for estimating DIF you can refer to Crane et al. 2007 (linked), and for a reproducible example of DIF analysis in R you can refer to vignettes in the lordif package.

The presence of Differential Item Functioning (DIF) means that the item is not operating/functioning/measuring in the same fashion for one group as it is for another group.  This means that the item changes the nature by which it measures the ability under question from one group to another.
The parameter associate with this is $\beta_3$ (not $\beta_2$).  If you want an instrument that measures people in the same fashion (regardless of their actual ability levels), then you want the same “slope” for the logistic curve.  If the slope is very steep for one group but shallow for another group, this means that, based on your ability level, you either know the answer or not (the steep slope group) or your chances of guessing the answer gradually increase as your overall understanding ($\theta$) increases (the shallow slope group).  For measurement theory purposes...this is not ideal.  Thus, we want no DIF (or $\beta_3=0$).
So, ¿what is the interpretation of $\beta_2$?  Well, this just tells you were the “average” ability is for the group.  (More specifically, it tells you were the average random-guessing point for that group would be for response $Y$ for the group...but this essentially equates to one group being higher or lower on the latent scale than the other group.)  And this really is what measurement theory is about...to determine where one group is on the ability scale compared to another group.['
Thus, it is OK for $\beta_2$ to be different (it simply implies the groups are not at the same ability level).  But, this is ONLY true if $\beta_3$ is essentially zero (meaning there is no DIF).

Thank you for your response! However, I'm not sure I agree that $\beta_2$ reflects differences in ability level; because model 2 includes both $\beta_1\theta$ and $\beta_{2}group$, $\beta_{2}$ represents the effect of group on response after controlling for ability. Thus, it can't simply reflect differences in ability level across groups, no?

This will be tricky to explain in a single comment...I'll break it apart.  PART #1  The intercept for a latent variable is meaningless on its own.  If you have one group, the intercept is the point along the ability scale where there is 50/50 chance of getting the item right or wrong.  This corresponds to a certain ability level along the scale, but as the scale is arbitrarily positions (an interval measure), this can be arbitrarily set to zero.  (That is why equation (1) is $Y=\beta_1 \theta$ instead of $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1\theta$.

PART #2 This doesn't hold when you have 2 or more groups.  Now the latent scale is being "repositioned" for each group (to the point where the 50/50 split occurs for the ability levels in each group.  One group is arbitrarily set to a position of zero, and the other groups are then positioned in comparison to that group (thus the need for the $\beta_2$ term.  Conceptually, the correct interpretation here is to "assign" a value for $\theta$ to everyone in group 1 (based on their performances on all the items) and then to "assign" a value of $\theta + \beta_2$ to everyone in group 2.

PART #3  The idea is that the scale is operating the same for each group, but the overall ability level of group 2 is just, on average, higher than group 1.  Thus, the item is functioning the same for the ability levels given (it is just that ability levels are not equal from one group to another).  [If I get a chance later today, I'll see if I can generate some R syntax to plot this.]

I really appreciate your continued input here, although I'm worried that we may be talking past each other. In the method I'm describing, $\theta$ is first estimated for the full sample (both groups). The difference in $Y$ attributable to $group$ ($\beta_2$) is conditional on $\theta$, so it's not just a difference in ability levels. I added a plot to the original post to help illustrate what I'm describing. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your point!

To your last point, there are items where the average score (and average ability level) are higher in one group, but the $\beta_2$ coefficient favors the other group.

@ila the answer and comments above are correct; the $\beta_2$ corresponds to an average group difference effect for the $\theta$s, and does not indicate DIF. It does indicate something known as impact, which is a reflection of whether the groups differ in their $\theta$ distributions and their respective moments. This is why it's important to scale/equate the differences between groups prior to testing for DIF, otherwise groups difference give the (potentially) false impression of DIF.

w.r.t, to your plot, if your groups were equated first so that they are on the same latent variable scale then the response curves would look more similar, unless DIF is present. If there's no DIF in the population the response functions would be identical.... assuming of course that the select functional form for the item is itself a reasonable approximation of the population's response behaviour.

Thank you! I'm upvoting all of these comments.
(1) The thetas in the plot were estimated for the entire dataset (i.e., both groups), using an IRT model where item parameters were constrained to be equal across groups, so the $\theta$s are on the same scale. Therefore, if I'm understanding your second comment correctly, the differences in the response curves do indicate DIF?
(2) I still do not understand how $\beta_2$ corresponds to the "average group difference effect for the $\theta$s," since the DV in the model is observed response and $\theta$ is in fact a covariate in the model.

Here is another example that I think will illustrate my conundrum. In the fully constrained model, the average $\theta$ for the HMS group is 0.27, and the average $\theta$ for the NHANES group is -0.77. For item 1 (anhedonia), the mean raw score is 1.02 for HMS and 0.39 for NHANES. Clearly, the HMS group is more depressed, and experiences more anhedonia, than NHANES. However, according to model (2) for item 1, after controlling for $\theta$, the $\beta_2$ coefficient for the effect of the HMS group is -0.15 log odds (OR = 0.86).

"The thetas in the plot were estimated for the entire dataset (i.e., both groups), using an IRT model where item parameters were constrained to be equal across groups, so the  s are on the same scale." Setting the item parameters as the same doesn't necessarily equate the metrics unless the $\theta$ distributions are also equated. This is why you're seeing a shift in the predicted probability plots as the functions are absorbing the impact effect. Also note, if an item does contain DIF this will contaminate the $\hat{\theta}$ terms as the model is misspecified.

For 2), groups often have different $\theta$ distributions, where one group has a higher mean than the other, so $Y$ would be higher on average for those in the more abled group and therefore have higher predicted $\hat{Y}$ values. Hence, if you do not account for the impact effect ($\beta_2$) then an item might appear easier/more difficult for one group (lower $\hat{Y}$), which could be misconstrued as bias rather than general $\theta$ differences. DIF is bias w.r.t. to the same underlying $\theta$ being scored differently, not whether items appear more difficult on average between groups.

I appreciate both of you lending your expertise to this question, and I can't in good conscience keep asking follow-ups in this thread, so I'll accept this answer. I may need to get back to basics w/r/t IRT!

I'm sorry I can't help it - one more comment. Would you disagree with this assessment, from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6072859/? Referring to their equation 3 (analogous to my equation 2): "If β2 ≠ 0 and β3 = 0, then an item shows uniform DIF, thereby implying that item difficulty parameters differ among groups. If β3 ≠ 0, then non-uniform DIF has occurred, and item discrimination parameters differ across groups."

This seems to be a claim made in at least a few papers, including https://hqlo.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1477-7525-8-81 ("The presence of uniform DIF is evaluated by testing whether the regression coefficient of group membership ($\beta_2$) differs significantly from zero") and https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/education/articles/10.3389/feduc.2017.00051/full ("If there is a significant group effect (i.e., $\beta_2\neq0$), the item is flagged as uniform DIF.")

The models are slightly different in that what you've referred to is conditional on $X$, the total scores, rather than $\theta$, which may or may not have already been equated. Totals scores differ as a function of both DIF and impact.
